# When you see me you smile

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I came up with this one myself:

> When you see me you smile, 
> I only stay a while, 
> think outside the box my friend, 
> until you bring me to my end.
> Where did my buddy go? 
> Their name had the sound of low.
> Who am I, and who is my buddy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Might you be:

> a nicely wrapped **PRESENT**?

*When you see me you smile,*

> Receiving a present generally makes a person happy and puts a smile on their face.

*I only stay a while,*

> But the present itself has only a temporary existence - it will soon be unwrapped to reveal what it truly is.
>  <sub>Furthermore (thanks to @QuantumTwinkie in comments), 'the present' (as in 'the here and now') only lasts a moment before it becomes 'the past' and part of history...</sub>

*think outside the box my friend,*
*until you bring me to my end.*

> Until you open the present ('*bring me to my end*') you do not know what is inside the wrapped box. You can speculate about its contents, but you are quite literally thinking *outside the box* all the while it remains wrapped up.

*Where did my buddy go?*
*Their name had the sound of low.*

> Once the paper and other wrapping materials are removed, they are taken away. Your 'buddy' who has now gone is a decorative **BOW** (which rhymes with 'low').

Comment: Also, for line 2, rot13(Gur cerfrag bayl ynfgf hagvy vg orpbzrf gur cnfg)

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie Ooh, that's a nice spin! I'll add that with credit, thanks...

Answer (score 3):

You could be

> a bullet

Your buddy could be

> a Submachine gun

When you see me you smile,

> Looking at your reflection near the end of the bullets tip, your mouth may appear to be smiling due to the distorting curve.

I only stay a while,

> The bullet only stays still for a while until fired.

think outside the box my friend,

> Bullets are kept in boxes.

until you bring me to my end.

> Bullets are spent/fired by striking their ends.

Where did my buddy go?

> The bullet was fired and no longer with its buddy, the gun.

Their name had the sound of low.

> Had trouble finding things that reference to low, so - *SUB* - machine gun or SMG.

Answer (score 1):

If you are inspired by William Wordsworth for writing poems it could be:

> Rainbow and the Sun

because

> We smile when we see it... it never comes alone... it only stays till his buddy is there... but sadly or happily we can't end it...

Comment: The OP has already accepted a correct answer.